# Wordpress Plugin Development Ajax and posting to database/admin email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am currently working my way through building my first Wordpress contact us plugin for a website I am currently working on.

I have made the following progress so far -

- Plugin displays in plugin list in WP dashboard
- When activated a new table is created in the database for storing the responses
- Menu item displays in WP dashboard to view form responses
- JQuery validation is working - when a user tries to submit the form without entering data or incorrect data an error message appears.

I am stuck on the form submission part of the process which I am using AJAX to submit the form without refreshing the page. I am unsure of how to submit the form without refreshing the page and in the process an email containing the form response is sent to the administrators email and posted to the database and the WP dashboard.

I have included all my code below - if someone could help me out and get it working it would be much appreciated.

**contact_us_form.php**

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Contact Us Form Plugin
Plugin URI: iphonerepair.ie
Description: Contact us form with validaton - sends email and posts responses to database and WP dashboard. 
Version: 1.0
Author URI: jms-design.co.uk
*/

if(!defined('WPINC'))
{
die;
}

// create table at plugin activition
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'jms_create_db' );
function jms_create_db() 
{
 global $wpdb;
 $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
 $table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'contactusform';
 $sql="CREATE TABLE $table_name(
  id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  time datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
        telno int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
        town varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
        device varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  message text,
  UNIQUE KEY id (id)
  ) $charset_collate;";
 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
 dbDelta( $sql );
}

//adding plugin to admin menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'jms_menu');
function jms_menu() 
{
 add_menu_page(__('Contact Form','jms'), __('Contact Form','jms'),
   'administrator', 'jms-contact-form', 'jms_settings_page', 'dashicons-email');
 function jms_settings_page() 
  {
   global $wpdb;
   $table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'contactusform';
   $client_msg = $wpdb->get_results( 
   "
   SELECT *
   FROM $table_name
   "
  );
   require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'settings-page.php');
  }
  
}

function cf_jms()
{
 ob_start();
 require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'form.php');
 return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'jms_contact_form', 'cf_jms' );

//if you want to have both logged in and not logged in users submitting, you have to add both actions!
add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', 'jms_admin_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_add_foobar', 'jms_admin_add_foobar' );
function jms_admin_add_foobar() {
    global $wpdb;
    $data = array(
        'time'  => current_time('mysql'),
        'name'  => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['name']),
        'telno'  => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['telno']),
        'email' => isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? sanitize_email( $_POST['email']) : null,
        'town'  => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['town']),
        'device'  => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['device']),
        'message'   => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['message'])
    );

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'starkod';
    $headers = array( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );
    // send Email for admin
    wp_mail(
        get_option( 'admin_email' ),
        'Instant Qoute/Callback Form',
        'Time : ' . $data['time'] .
        'Name : ' . $data['name'] .
        'Tel No : ' . $data['telno'] .
        'Email : ' . $data['email'] .
        'Town : ' . $data['town'] .
        'Device : ' . $data['device'] .
        ' The message: ' . $data['message'],         
        $headers
    );

    if ( $wpdb->insert( $table_name, $data ) ) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Your Message received , thanks ";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "there's problem try again please";
    }
    //redirect back to where user was comming
    wp_redirect( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
    //request handlers should die() when they complete their task
}

?>
```

**form.php**

```html
<form class="contactusform" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
<?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['message']))
 {
 echo $_SESSION['message'];
 unset($_SESSION['message']);
 }
 ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_foobar">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="foobarid">
  <label>Full Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" value="" required="">
  <label>Phone Number:</label><input type"=text" name="telno" value="" required="">
  <label>Email Address:</label><input type="email" name="email" value="" required="">
  <label>Town:</label><input type"=text" name="town" value="" required="">
  <label>Device:</label><select name="device" value="" required="">
  <option selected="selected" value=""></option><option value="Not Sure">Not Sure</option><option selected="selected" value=""></option><option value="iPhone 3G">iPhone 3G</option><option value="iPhone 3GS">iPhone 3GS</option><option value="iPhone 4G">iPhone 4G</option><option value="iPhone 4S">iPhone 4S</option><option value="iPhone 5">iPhone 5</option><option value="iPhone 5C">iPhone 5C</option><option value="iPhone 5S">iPhone 5S</option><option value="iPhone 6">iPhone 6</option><option value="iPhone 6 Plus">iPhone 6 Plus</option><option selected="selected" value=""></option><option value="MacBook">MacBook</option><option value="MacBook Pro">MacBook Pro</option><option value="MacBook Air">MacBook Air</option><option selected="selected" value=""></option><option value="iMac">iMac</option><option selected="selected" value=""></option><option value="iPad 1">iPad 1</option><option value="iPad 2">iPad 2</option><option value="iPad 3">iPad 3</option><option value="iPad 4">iPad 4</option><option value="iPad Air">iPad Air</option><option value="iPad Air 2">iPad Air 2</option><option value="iPad Mini 1">iPad Mini 1</option><option value="iPad Mini 2">iPad Mini 2</option><option value="iPad Mini 3">iPad Mini 3</option><option selected="selected" value=""></option><option value="iPod Classic">iPod Classic</option><option value="iPod Mini">iPod Mini</option><option value="iPod Nano">iPod Nano</option><option value="iPod Shuffle">iPod Shuffle</option><option value="iPod Touch">iPod Touch</option>
 </select>
 <label>Message:</label><textarea name="msg" cols="30" rows="4" value="" required=""></textarea>
 <input class="submit2" type="submit">
</form>

<div id="success">
        <p>Your message was sent successfully! I will be in touch as soon as I can.</p>
</div>

<div id="error">
        <p>Something went wrong, try refreshing and submitting the form again.</p>
</div>
```

**settings-page.php**

```html
<div class="wrap">
<h3><?php esc_attr_e( 'Instant Quote/Callback Requests', 'jms' ); ?></h3>
<table class="widefat">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th><?php esc_attr_e( 'Time', 'jms' ); ?></th>
    <th><?php esc_attr_e( 'Name', 'jms' ); ?></th>
 <th><?php esc_attr_e( 'Telephone Number', 'jms' ); ?></th>
 <th><?php esc_attr_e( 'Email Address', 'jms' ); ?></th>
 <th><?php esc_attr_e( 'Town', 'jms' ); ?></th>
 <th><?php esc_attr_e( 'Device', 'jms' ); ?></th>
 <th><?php esc_attr_e( 'Message', 'jms' ); ?></th>
 
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php foreach($client_msg as $client): ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php esc_attr_e($client->time,'jms');?></td>
  <td><?php esc_attr_e($client->name,'jms');?></td>
  <td><?php esc_attr_e($client->telno,'jms');?></td>
  <td><?php esc_attr_e($client->email,'jms');?></td>
  <td><?php esc_attr_e($client->town,'jms');?></td>
   <td><?php esc_attr_e($client->device,'jms');?></td>
  <td><?php esc_attr_e($client->msg,'jms');?></td>
 
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>  
 </tbody>
  
</table>
</div>
```

**validation code**

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.32/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\bcat\b$/.test(value);
    }, "type the correct answer -_-");

// validate contact form
$(function() {
    $('.contactusform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            telno: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                number: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            town: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            device: {
                required: true
            },
            msg: {
                required: true
            },
        
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter your full name.",
                minlength: "Your full name must consist of at least 2 characters."
            },
            telno: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number.",
                minlength: "Your phone number must consist of at least 8 characters."
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address."
            },
            town: {
                required: "Please enter your town.",
                minlength: "Your town must consist of at least 2 characters."
            },
            device: {
                required: "Please select your device."
            },
            msg: {
                required: "Please enter your message."
            },
        
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                type:"POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                url:"<?=admin_url()?>admin-post.php",
                success: function() {
                    $('.contactusform :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('.contactusform').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                        $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                        $('#success').fadeIn();
                    });
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#contactusform').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                        $('#error').fadeIn();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**process.php (unsure if this code is needed...)**

```html
<?php

    $to = "youremail@domain.com";
    $from = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $headers = "From: $from";
    $subject = "You have a message.";

    $fields = array();
    $fields{"name"} = "name";
    $fields{"email"} = "email";
    $fields{"phone"} = "phone";
    $fields{"message"} = "message";

    $body = "Here is what was sent:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

If anyone could help me make this work I would be very grateful.

Many Thanks
Joshua

Comment: This question should be deleted as it isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the jquery I use for that which I usually add to wp_enqueue_script js folder

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // grab the submits button ID. do not use <input type="submit"> inside the form. Use a button instead outside the form.
    $("#submit2").click(function()
    {
        // grab the forms ID
        $("#message").submit(function(e)
        {
            // add a loading image in place of your returning outcome
            $("#simple-msg").html("sending...");

            // serialize/combine all submitted fields into an array
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();

            // set url based of action
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

            // set ajax parameters
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
            e.unbind();
        });

        $("#message").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
    });

});
```

I also updated your form with the needed fields, but keep in mind your forms action since you will need to make it point to the page that processes your form

```
<form name='message' id='message' class="contactusform" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/your-plugins-name/process.php">
<?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['message']))
 {
 echo $_SESSION['message'];
 unset($_SESSION['message']);
 }
 ?>
     <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_foobar">
     <input type="hidden" name="data" value="foobarid">
     <label>Full Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" value="" required="">
     <label>Phone Number:</label><input type"=text" name="telno" value="" required="">
     <label>Email Address:</label><input type="email" name="email" value="" required="">
     <label>Town:</label><input type"=text" name="town" value="" required="">
     <label>Device:</label><select name="device" value="" required="">
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option><option value="Not Sure">Not Sure</option><option selected="selected" value=""></option><option value="iPhone 3G">iPhone 3G</option><option value="iPhone 3GS">iPhone 3GS</option><option value="iPhone 4G">iPhone 4G</option><option value="iPhone 4S">iPhone 4S</option><option value="iPhone 5">iPhone 5</option><option value="iPhone 5C">iPhone 5C</option><option value="iPhone 5S">iPhone 5S</option><option value="iPhone 6">iPhone 6</option><option value="iPhone 6 Plus">iPhone 6 Plus</option><option selected="selected" value=""></option><option value="MacBook">MacBook</option><option value="MacBook Pro">MacBook Pro</option><option value="MacBook Air">MacBook Air</option><option selected="selected" value=""></option><option value="iMac">iMac</option><option selected="selected" value=""></option><option value="iPad 1">iPad 1</option><option value="iPad 2">iPad 2</option><option value="iPad 3">iPad 3</option><option value="iPad 4">iPad 4</option><option value="iPad Air">iPad Air</option><option value="iPad Air 2">iPad Air 2</option><option value="iPad Mini 1">iPad Mini 1</option><option value="iPad Mini 2">iPad Mini 2</option><option value="iPad Mini 3">iPad Mini 3</option><option selected="selected" value=""></option><option value="iPod Classic">iPod Classic</option><option value="iPod Mini">iPod Mini</option><option value="iPod Nano">iPod Nano</option><option value="iPod Shuffle">iPod Shuffle</option><option value="iPod Touch">iPod Touch</option>
    </select>
    <label>Message:</label><textarea name="msg" cols="30" rows="4" value="" required=""></textarea>
</form>
<input type='button' id='submit2' value='Send Message' />
<div id='simple-msg'></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer - added your code - I see you've mentioned in form.php to link it to the process.php file? I'm not sure what I have to include in this file? When I fill in the fields and click on send - the message sending... appears and an image of the webpage shows underneath but nothing appears in the database. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I looked at your code, but don't see a script for saving the posted data into your table "contactusform". You need to create a query for that. At the moment it's just sending out emails using process.php "The file you said you where unsure if the code was needed" Also take a look at the forms action path and make sure it points to file that saves to your database. The reason you're seeing a webpage is because your actions path points to a non empty page. Keep in mind that it's ajax so your file should not contain a header, footer, etc. and only the processing script with a status message.

Comment: Ok Galfaro I have got it working - its posting to the database and displaying in the WP dashboard - I am not sure about sending email as I will have to put it live to test it. I set the action on the form to <?=admin_url()?>admin-post.php. And the function for posting to the db / sending an email is in the contact_us_form.php snippet at the top of this post - its called function jms_admin_add_foobar(). I didn't need to use process.php at all. Can you take a quick a look and see if you think anything else is needed?

Comment: I actually didn't see your submitHandler function which is why I thought you didn't have a query to you database, so that was my mistake. I now see why process.php is not being used. As for what else is needed I believe you should be fine now. Just make sure you sanitize your data before saving it to your db.

Comment: I think I already have the data sanatized - I have used the sanitize text field function - see example - 'telno'  => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['telno']), is this the correct way of sanitizing the data? Also regarding the validation end of things - could I work my existing validation script into this plugin or would I need to start from scratch - if yes could you show me an example of how you validate each field before the user submits a form? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you could do $telno = sanitize_text_field($_POST['telno']; and then place $telno anywhere you like. As for using your own validation that's fine, but I usually let Wordpress handle that. Here's a link with all the sanitization types that Wordpress handles. I think it's a lot easier than making my own. Also if you found my post helpful can you mark it as solved. Thanks!  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field